# Quickblox Android sample video chat - Distorted video stream

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox, videochat, quickblox-android

In case somebody experiences the same issue (and for a better visibility) I'll also post this question and its answer here ([Original thread](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/217)):

I have successfully installed and ran the sample video chat app on several different Android devices. Only on my Samsung Tab A running Android 5.0.2 the incoming video streams are showing up distorted after about 20-30 seconds:

[image]

I have gone through the logs an figured out that a "decoder format changed" message is logged simultaneously with the video getting messed up:

```
06-06 10:00:09.779 31260-6050/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Decoder format changed: {image-data=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=80,capacity=80], mime=video/raw, crop-top=0, crop-right=639, slice-height=480, color-format=19, height=480, width=640, what=1869968451, crop-bottom=479, crop-left=0, stride=640}
06-06 10:00:33.499 31260-6050/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Decoder format changed: {image-data=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=80,capacity=80], mime=video/raw, crop-top=0, crop-right=479, slice-height=384, color-format=19, height=360, width=480, what=1869968451, crop-bottom=359, crop-left=0, stride=512}
```

Has anybody experienced a similar issue and can provide me with some ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with the settings I found a workaround for this issue. By deactivating the hardware acceleration on affected devices, the distorted video stopped to appearing during the video chat.

```
QBRTCMediaConfig.setVideoHWAcceleration(false);
```